# Formatting get_the_date items within Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I know I can change the color and size of the date within a single entry page via css that's already in place but how can I format the individual items within the get_the_date call?

Right now if I use `('j M. Y')` I will get "26 Nov. 2014" on one line. I want to be able to have this display as:

## 26

### Nov. 2014

As you can see, the date is on a line by itself and is larger than the Mon. Year line.

The page that I am editing is template_tags.php and the line that I am editing is

```
esc_html( get_the_date('j M. Y') )
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wound up doing:

```
'<div align="center" style="display:block"><span id="da1">&nbsp;'. esc_html( get_the_date( 'j' ) ). '</span><br><span style="font-size:10px;display:block;">'.esc_html( get_the_date( 'M. Y' ) ) . '</span>')
```

No echo needed

Thanks everyone!

Comment: There definitely has to be an `echo` in there somewhere (probably before the statement above)...Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 2):

Break it up into different items. For example:

```
echo '<div class="day">' . esc_html( get_the_date("j") ) . '</div>';
echo '<div class="month-year">' . esc_html( get_the_date("M. Y") ) . '</div>';
```

You can then target each of these `<div>`s via their CSS class names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the template tag twice:

```
echo '<span class="date_1">' . esc_html( get_the_date( 'j' ) ) . '</span>';
echo '<span class="date_2">' . esc_html( get_the_date( 'M. Y' ) ) . '</span>';
```

Comment: To the OP: if you choose to go this route, keep in mind that `span` is an inline element, and won't automatically result in the two dates on different lines, unless you change them to `display: block;` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo esc_html(get_the_date( 'j' )); ?>&nbsp;<br />
<?php echo esc_html(get_the_date("M. Y")); ?>
```